# Thinkbook GEN4 secureboot

Tags: linux, boot, debian

Got the latest 4th generation of thinkpad, trying to get secureboot working on it in Debian by following:

https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot

To enroll a key:

$ sudo mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der # prompts for one-time password

At next reboot, the device firmware should launch it's MOK manager and prompt the user to review the new key and confirm it's enrollment, using the one-time password. Any kernel modules (or kernels) that have been signed with this MOK should now be loadable.

At this point I'm stuck because no manager comes up at next reboot, if I enable SB I get nowhere because I can't boot anything but win11 on the laptop.

If I do this process then enable SB there will be no popup again...

Did anyone get this working?

Comment: What are the currently installed Secure Boot `db` keys (the firmware should have a list somewhere) – do they include Microsoft's "third party CA" key? The MOK manager (and the whole concept of a MOK) is usually _not_ part of firmware; it is part of Shim which is a pre-bootloader that Debian uses – do you have that installed?

Comment: ii  shim-signed:amd64                                           1.39+15.7-1                                     amd64        Secure Boot chain-loading bootloader (Microsoft-signed binary)
ii  shim-signed-common                                          1.39+15.7-1                                     all          
ii  shim-unsigned

Comment: Did anyone get this working is very poor way of phrasing a question, can be answered by yes/no.

Comment: go fuck yourself troll